# Navigating from Activity to Fragment using Up Navigation Pattern in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have ListFragments inside the ViewPager, each `ListFragment` is contained inside an activity and has its own option Menu Items which the user can click/tap to start an Activity named as `addEditItem`. Now i want to [provide up navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) in the `addEditItem` activity, Pressing the Home button (Up Button) in that activity will return back to a `ListFragment`. I dont know if we can specify a `Fragment` as parent of an `Activity` as we can [specify activies.](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent) What i am trying inside `optionsItemSelectedItem` inside `addEditItem` activity is as follows(But this is throughing `NullPointerException at navigateUpTo`):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new
            // task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "navigate up to");
            try {

                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;        

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```